# Prevent Windows 10 from updating modified date on folders when renaming files inside of them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, date-modified

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?
Say I want to rename a file *B.TXT* inside folder *A* but I don't want the modified date of the folder *A* to be updated to today's date, how can I (if I actually can) achieve this?

Currently what I was doing is opening with Attribute Changer (context menu) the folder before any renaming done and then after renaming the files I applied the dates the folder previously had (it automatically grabs the original dates, so I only had to click on Apply). This is a pain in the ass when you rename a lot of files from a lot of folders, so I'm looking for a way of stopping Windows to update the dates of the folder only when renaming, of course I prefer the dates updated when I copy, move, delete or create any files/folders, but I don't when only renaming them.

Thanks.